# Problem with adding custom CSS class to image in ACF Photo Gallery plugin

Tags: php, functions, custom-field, css, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the ACF Photo Gallery plugin (ACF addon that adds an image gallery option). I'm trying to add the option of giving my own CSS class to a particular image, all by the tutorial -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/navz-photo-gallery/ (Usage, Add Extra Field), but unfortunately for some reason the CSS class does not appear In the code. I paste below my comment code (there is not much). Where did I make a mistake?

```
/// I put this to functions.php, in edition in particular image window appears with css class field
<?php
function my_extra_gallery_fields( $args, $attachment_id, $field ){
    $args['class'] = array('type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Kolor produktu', 'name' => 'class', 'value' => get_field($field . '_class', $attachment_id) );  /// I think the problem may be here
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'acf_photo_gallery_image_fields', 'my_extra_gallery_fields', 10, 3 );
?>
/// I put this code to single-portfolio.php
<?php
    $images = acf_photo_gallery('gallery_images', $post->ID); /// gallery_images to slug pola galeria w ACF
    if( count($images) ):
        foreach($images as $image):
            $full_image_url= $image['full_image_url'];
            $class = get_field('gallery_images_class', $id);
    endforeach; endif;
?>  
/// This code displays image, CSS class should appers, but it doesn't
<?php foreach($images as $image) { ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $image['full_image_url']; ?>" class="<?php echo $class; ?>" >
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code at the place where you want your gallery:

```
<?php
$images = acf_photo_gallery('gallery_images', $post->ID); /// gallery_images to slug pola galeria w ACF
if( count($images) ):
    foreach($images as $image):
        $full_image_url= $image['full_image_url'];
        $class = get_field('gallery_images_class', $id);
        echo '<img src="'.$image['full_image_url'].'" class="'.$class.'" >';
endforeach; endif;
?>
```

Do try to check if '$id' gives you the image/post id (not sure what is needed here).

EDIT: 
Please check if `$id` and `$class` are correct. you can do this by using this code:

```
<?php
$images = acf_photo_gallery('gallery_images', $post->ID); /// gallery_images to slug pola galeria w ACF
if( count($images) ):
    foreach($images as $image):
        $full_image_url= $image['full_image_url'];
        $class = get_field('gallery_images_class', $image['id']);
        echo '<img src="'.$image['full_image_url'].'" class="'.$class.'" >';
endforeach; endif;
?>
```

It could be possible that `$image' in your foreach has an ID. Try to use that one instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, it is the same as before. I tried 'echo $id' and I received post ID. I think I need images ID? What you suggest?

Comment: @Marek check my edit!

Comment: OK, I pasted your new code and I received blank page, but in source code in the place where the slider should be I see "int(2278)
bool(false)". 2278 - this is the post ID.

Comment: @Marek can you change ` die(var_dump($id, $class));` to ` die(var_dump($image));` ? And then post it on pastebin and give us the link?

Comment: OK, link to pastebin after change to var_dump($image) -> https://pastebin.com/Yrw7KCb6

Comment: ok, change `$class = get_field('gallery_images_class', $id);` to `$class = get_field('gallery_images_class', $image['id']);` and then change `die(var_dump($image));` to `die(var_dump($image['id'], $class));`

Comment: OK, I received: "int(2286)
string(5) "green". "green" is the CSS class!

Comment: Now just remove the `die(var_dump($image['id'], $class));` and it should work if i am not mistaken

Comment: I hope you have a bit more sense about how to 'debug' these issues in the future. Just check the output with `var_dump()`. But mostly I use it with `die()` so that the script won't get executed any further! And thanks for the edit. Wanted to just do that!